Having problems running flask-app on CGI - app code works, htaccess (probably) breaks it
I am trying to run a Flask Webapp with simple Login/Logoff Functionality (for now). It is a simple a small private project. As i do not have any WSGI-options with my shared hosting provider, i have to use CGI (must not start any services due to terms of shared hosting).
When using a development server locally, everything works perfectly. But when i want to open it up on the shared hosting service, it breaks.
At first i had various other problems that prevented the files from even loading correctly (thanks to everyone up here, i fixed that).
Now: If i am trying to access my domain normally, i should be redirected to https://example.com/login (thats the route i have set in the app), and after login is processed i should be taken to / (which has a login_required decorator). This works - as mentioned - perfectly on localhost.
On the webserver this happens:
I am accessing my domain - i get redirected to: https://example.com/index.cgi/login?next=%2Findex.cgi%2F
When i try to login, nothing happens. I am redirected to the correct url then, but nothing happens.
I would guess that my htaccess is not properly configured as everything else is working.. do you have any ideas? Thanks!
My filestructure looks like this:
|- web
|-- folder my domain points to
|---- templates (login.html, index.html, etc.)
|---- app.py (main file)
|---- config.py (database connection config)
|---- .htaccess
|---- index.cgi

|- venv (python venv with needed packages) - contains a wrapper in bin to be able to use the correct python environment in the cgi files shebang

.htaccess
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/sites/site00000000/web/foldername/index.cgi/$1 [QSA,L]

index.cgi
#!/home/sites/site00000000/venv/bin/wrapper.sh
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")

from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler

from app import app

CGIHandler().run(app)

app.py is nothing special, flask_login is used, and routes are configured, i am not including this, as i am not sure if that would help and it's a bit long :D.
Thank you for reading & feel free to ask if anythings unclear. Thanks in advance for you help :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531482/how-to-get-rid-of-extra-cgi-bin-url-components-running-a-flask-app-using-wsgiref
This helped me get rid of the "index.cgi" in the URL. However, my login form is not working (it's simply doing nothing at all - redirecting me to the same page when clicking on submit) .. any ideas?
